# Shinobi Chart Android alter Tick label

Tags: android, shinobi

I have a requirement where i need to alter the tick label of the axis so as to show additional information on the axis on Shinobi Chart on Android.

I'm aware that on iOS we can use -(void)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart alterTickMark:(SChartTickMark *)tickMark beforeAddingToAxis:(SChartAxis *)axis delegate method to do the same.

I was wondering if any similar api is available to do the same on Android.

Comment: I have a feeling that this isn't currently available, but it is coming soon. For more info you should email the support team or pop a question on their support forums

Answer (score -3):

I work for ShinobiControls and I can confirm that equivalent Android functionality will be included in the upcoming release of ShinobiCharts for Android. This release should provisionally be available early to mid June.